# Bytes string not splitting properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a byte string:

```
a = b'\x11\xee\x8f\xed\xb3]\x0f\x843^\xcaU\x9c\r+_TfK\x86\xd5\x94\xcc\xc5\xec[%U\xe0Z\xd2p\xaa\x83\xdc\x90?!l.\xc4K\xae\xd6)\x99\xf0\xb7\\\xb6\nb\x128$*\x0c\xbd&\x87\r\x9a\x8fx\xfc&\xf6r\xc11^O\x19\x0e8\xec\xcb\xfb07\x88\x968\xc6wm\x97\xb3\xe4\xff2\\N\xcf\x97\xd2\x95s?\xb1\xfd=\x9e\x99\ttu#\xbb\xdf\xed e\xcbO,\xf5\xa8\xe4\xcfIC\xda\x98\xff\xa5\xb6\x07~\xe5\xcb\xeb\xda\xc4\x80"\x89\xff\x05\xac0q\x97Jm\xabM\xc1Id\xdcN\xea\xe6<\x16\xb2\x8aQ5\xc0W\x04\x19\xfa\t\xb5::\x8bpI\'\x93\x8at\xae\\\xa0\xd2\x1dJ\xc0\xe8\x8eG\x17\xb6i\xf8\xe4\xf3\xc1\xb69\xe2t\xbb\xf6\x9c\xb2Ar>\xdb\xc7\xdb\x85e\x04&\x04\x05\xa4\x90\x87\xda<\x00#\xc1\xfa\x8eG.\x1aBS2\xee\xfb\xae\xf3=\xbeM\x9d\xbd6\xf5H\xa6*7\xcfSK\xbb\xf3M\xde:\xa0U\xd3%\x93hRl\xe3S\x7f\xd8;\xd6;\x013\xad2go\xc3\'\x89\x18\\\xc4NR\x848\x12\x1c\xf1d\xc8\x14e@\x82I\xd7\xdd6\n\rAaY\xb2\xbb\xd5\xd4aw\xc3V\x089\x8b!D\xaa+\xfaRvB5u\x8b\x83\xb1\x8f\xb0\x9f%\xab\xc4\xea\xde\x05\xa01\x05\xc2]F\'\xfb*\x1c\xfa\x05E\xec\xa60\x10\xbc\xab\x9b\x821\xe9\x8ef\x19\xda\x01\x81k\xf8"e&\x88\x13\x032\xcb\x8c[\x14\xbb\xba5\x81\xaa{\xa6W@\xc0\x8e\xc6\x80\x8ek\x07hy\xb2\x99w\xbe3\xc6\x95f\x9a\xe8[\xf0\xf0U\x16\x8d;?zm\xb3b\x8d\xc0\x93\xb8\xc6\x99\xcdA"\xa2\xd9#\x1f\xb1\xc3i\xbe5y\\\xe0m@=\xcb\xc8|\xf1\x1fp7\xf6uuE\xfd\r\xa28P\xcc\x1b\x9e]\x08\xd1k\x84\x0b2\xe1\xf2)\x84p\x13\xbb\xe1\x86\xec?`m\x1dYk\xf2y\xe2=d\xff8?6\xf7\x19\x9c\x81\x06ps\xa2\xa1^\n!\x14JPs {\xc0\x9b\xa1\xb4\xed\xb2\xb71\xd4\xcbgu\x86\x86\r\x9e\x83Gj\xa3\xb1|\x02HI\xbenVDL\xdf\xad \xc7f'
```

And i want to split it into 512 : 32 bytes

This is the code im using where b is the set of 512 bytes and c is the set of 32 bytes:

```
b = a[:32]
c = a[512:]
```

The 32 bytes separate properly but not the 512 bytes, instead of separating the first 512 bytes from the last 32 it is separating the first 32 bytes and the last 32 bytes and the middle part is lost:

```
c = b'\xb4\xed\xb2\xb71\xd4\xcbgu\x86\x86\r\x9e\x83Gj\xa3\xb1|\x02HI\xbenVDL\xdf\xad \xc7f'
b = b'\x11\xee\x8f\xed\xb3]\x0f\x843^\xcaU\x9c\r+_TfK\x86\xd5\x94\xcc\xc5\xec[%U\xe0Z\xd2p'
```

Comment: b = a[:32]
c = a[32:512]

Answer (score 0):

The description of what you want is confusing without describing what you want.

In a list slice (the [number:number] thing) the first number is the first index you want included (default is 0).  The second number is the slice is the index+1 (which defaults to the end of the list).
What you are saying is

```
b = a[:32]
```

"b" is the first 32 elements of "a" from 0 to 32  which could be thought of b = a[from 0 : to 32]

```
c = a[512:]
```

"c" is the elements of "a" starting at 512 to the end or you can think of it like c=a[from 512:to the end]